# Grouping images together in the middle of the page

Tags: html, css

I want my images to be aligned properly (Like 3 images per row) while there's, for example, 200 pixel space between images, and that there's a specific space between the "wall" and first/last image.
Thank you for the help.

This is how it looks: 
[image: current layout]

This is how I want it to look: 
[image: desired look]

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <li><a href="#" class="navbar-brand"> MMO/MMORPG </a>
    </li>
    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="./sakums.html">Sākums</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Galerija</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="./kontakti.html">Kontakti</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="./anketa.html">Anketa</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="http://images4.alphacoders.com/209/209608.jpg" title="TERA ONLINE">
    <img src="http://images4.alphacoders.com/209/209608.jpg" width="300" height="200" alt="Tera">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="http://www.1zoom.net/big2/753/262650-blackangel.jpg" title="BLADE&SOUL ONLINE">
    <img src="http://www.1zoom.net/big2/753/262650-blackangel.jpg" width="300" height="200" alt="BnS">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="http://wallfor.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/3346_guild_wars_2.jpg" title="GUILD WARS 2">
    <img src="http://wallfor.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/3346_guild_wars_2.jpg" width="300" height="200" alt="GW2">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="http://img.finalfantasyxiv.com/lds/pc/global/images/special/fankit/resource/pcw/ffxiv_pcw19002_1920x1080_en.jpg?1432793620" title="FINAL FANTASY XIV">
    <img src="http://img.finalfantasyxiv.com/lds/pc/global/images/special/fankit/resource/pcw/ffxiv_pcw19002_1920x1080_en.jpg?1432793620" width="300" height="200" alt="FFXIV">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="http://www.funmole.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/1360803180600.jpg" title="NEVERWINTER">
    <img src="http://www.funmole.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/1360803180600.jpg" width="300" height="200" alt="NW">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I created a code snippet but it doesn't look correct. Could you please alter it so it renders like your image does?

Comment: I'm not sure how code snippet works, but it does look different now. Also the images seems to work just like intended...

Comment: If you want to use bootstrap it should be something like this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/360/

Comment: It kinda did work, but now it looks like this. http://puu.sh/lTVNI/44128d320e.jpg  I'd like to get some space between the images..

Answer (score 0):

Try out this:

**html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="http://images4.alphacoders.com/209/209608.jpg" title="TERA ONLINE">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://images4.alphacoders.com/209/209608.jpg" width="300" height="200" alt="Tera"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="http://www.1zoom.net/big2/753/262650-blackangel.jpg" title="BLADESOUL ONLINE">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://images4.alphacoders.com/209/209608.jpg" width="300" height="200" alt="BnS"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="http://wallfor.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/3346_guild_wars_2.jpg" title="GUILD WARS 2">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://wallfor.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/3346_guild_wars_2.jpg" width="300" height="200" alt="GW2"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="http://img.finalfantasyxiv.com/lds/pc/global/images/special/fankit/resource/pcw/ffxiv_pcw19002_1920x1080_en.jpg?1432793620" title="FINAL FANTASY XIV">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://img.finalfantasyxiv.com/lds/pc/global/images/special/fankit/resource/pcw/ffxiv_pcw19002_1920x1080_en.jpg?1432793620" width="300" height="200" alt="FFXIV"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="http://images4.alphacoders.com/209/209608.jpg" title="TERA ONLINE">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://images4.alphacoders.com/209/209608.jpg" width="300" height="200" alt="Tera"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="http://www.1zoom.net/big2/753/262650-blackangel.jpg" title="BLADESOUL ONLINE">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://images4.alphacoders.com/209/209608.jpg" width="300" height="200" alt="BnS"></a>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
img {
  padding: 5%;
}
```

**UPDATE 1:** Updated css to use flexbox.

```
.row {
  margin: 3% 0%;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-align-content: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.row:nth-child(2) {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-pack: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-align-content: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-line-pack: start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

Output: **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/b74tgjdw/6/)**

Comment: Well, it does work like it's supposed to, but thanks to padding the images are little smaller now, and if you click on the blank space near the image, it still takes it as image. My teacher will find that to be an "error" and won't accept it.

Comment: @Arthur I have made the update. Kindly have a look at it.

Comment: Now a problem is that if you put it on windowed mode, the images will go over each other. And we haven't learned these "flex" commands yet, so I won't be able to explain to him what they are doing. But i am really glad you're trying to help me, I appreciate it.

Comment: Well, frankly speaking, this site is not to solve any queries related to what is given as homework. But still I've given my best to help you going against the rule of the site to a certain extent. I have provided the solution as per the question, now it is up to you to accept it or not.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for being like that. I still appreciate your effort because you did some things that I took and it worked. Thank you a lot for helping me, I've learned new things. :)

Comment: I'm glad to hear that.. Cheers.. :)